# RuntimeError in solving equation using SymPy

Tags: python, runtime-error, sympy, equation

[image]

I have a equation to solve. The equation can be described as the formula above. N and S are constants, for example N = 201 and S = 0.5. I use sympy in python to solve it. The python script is given as following:

```
from sympy import *

x=Symbol('x')
print solve( (((1-x)/200) **(1-x))* x**x - 2**(-0.5), x)
```

However, there is a **RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in __instancecheck__**

I have also tried to use Mathematica, and it can output a result of 0.963

[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(((1-x)%2F200)+**(1-x))*+x**x+-+2**(-0.5)+%3D+0](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(((1-x)%2F200)%20**(1-x))*%20x**x%20-%202**(-0.5)%20%3D%200)

[image]

Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: what is `s` in that equation?

Comment: S is the real entropy in mobility predictability research. For each person, we can estimate it. Thus, for an individual, S can be viewed as a constant, ranging from 0 to 1. Here we let S = 0.5, just for an example.

Comment: ah ok my bad. Didn't understand read properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you don't want a symbolic solution, just a value you can work with (like WA's 0.964), you can use `mpmath` for this. I'm not sure if it's actually possible to express the solution in radicals - WA certainly didn't even try. You should already have it installed as SymPy

```
Requires: mpmath
```

Specifically, [`mpmath.findroot`](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.6/modules/mpmath/calculus/optimization.html#root-finding-findroot) seems to do what you want. It takes an actual callable Python object which is the function to find a root of, and a starting value for x. It also accepts some more parameters such as the minimum error `tol` and the solver to use which you could play around with, although they don't really seem necessary. You could quite simply use it like this:

```
import mpmath

f = lambda x: (((1-x)/200) **(1-x))* x**x - 2**(-0.5)
print mpmath.findroot(f, 1)
```

I just used 1 as a starting value - you could probably think of a better one. Judging by the shape of your graph, there's only one root to be found and it can be approached quite easily, without much need for fancy solvers, so this should suffice. Also, considering that "mpmath is a Python library for arbitrary-precision floating-point arithmetic", you should be able to get a very high precision answer from this if you wished. It has the output of

```
(0.963904761592753 + 0.0j)
```

This is actually an mpmath complex or `mpc` object,

```
mpc(real='0.96390476159275343', imag='0.0')
```

If you know it will have an imaginary value of 0, you can just use either of the following methods:

```
In [6]: abs(mpmath.mpc(23, 0))
Out[6]: mpf('23.0')

In [7]: mpmath.mpc(23, 0).real
Out[7]: mpf('23.0')
```

to "extract" a single float in the format of an `mpf`.

Comment: It is a really great solution.  Thanks a lot